# File Permission, after copy c#

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, copy, mime

I have a problem on my C# webapp

I need to copy a file from some network path

`\\server01\sharedFolder\myfile.ext` to `inetpub/upload folder`, and show the link to the user download the ext file.

When i use `File.Copy` (C#) the file lost all permissions and the browser user can't download the file. The iis keeps asking a windows credential to download the generated file.

I've tried to register .ext mime type and set file permission using `FileSecurity.AddAccessRule` without success.

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Try launching your application in administrator mode. Im not to familiar with network file sharing protocol so I don't know anything after that though.

Comment: Create an FTP site on your server and send the files via FTP

Comment: You have to make the network folder shared and have correct permissions.  First try with a file explorer to check if you have access to each folder in the path.  Using file explorer will help you find the permission for the folders/files.  Then once you get working with file explorer the c# code should work.  Most companies use Network Folder (Group Policies) with windows credentials and using FTP is not necessary.

Comment: Is it taking on the parent folder permissions?

Comment: No is not taking on the parent folder permissions.... 

i copy the file.... then... lost all permissions :(